# Less command odd behaviour

Tags: bash, less-unix

I am trying to create a small tutorial-like script to refresh my bash skills.

I have defined a variable `DISPLAY_TEXT` that has some text and a set of escape characters and colors like so:

```
DISPLAY_TEXT=${WHITE}\n\t \t ==== $HEADER ====\n\n${NOCOL}"
```

`WHITE` and `NOCOL` defined with their appropriate ANSI escape codes.

Then, using a simple pipe with `echo`, I redirect the value of a variable `DISPLAY_TEXT` to `less` with `echo -e $DISPLAY_TEXT | less`.

The arguments I have set for less are as so:

```
less --prompt=["Navigate using arrows (or touchpad). Enter 'q' to exit"] -r
```

With `-r` to output raw characters.

*The program gets executed fine and the output is as expected* with colors showing (until I scroll down and up again). The main odd behaviour is displayed in the next picture.

[image: odd less]

Is there something I am not understanding with **basic** redirection, less or bash in general? This behaviour isn't limiting my script but it is something that I'm interested in understanding.

Comment: Can you describe what the odd behavior is?

Comment: The odd behaviour is as displayed in the picture. Navigating up and down after reaching the end of the file causes `less`(?) to re-print that specific line.  Maybe SO isn't the right community for this question, not sure.

Comment: Which specific line is being reprinted? I'm still not able to tell.

Comment: I think you need to be more precise about the command you typed to get the picture you present. Your question uses both `DISPLAY_COLOR` and `DISPLAY_TEXT`; you don't specify exactly which ANSI codes you use and "\n\t \t ==== $HEADER ====\n\n" does not correlate in any obvious way with the display (and there is apparently a missing or extra quote). So it's not easy to attempt to reproduce. Also, it would help if you mentioned what terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: `DISPLAY_COLOR` was a sleep induced typo. `DISPLAY_TEXT` is the variable I am using to display my text. The `tty` I am using is `/dev/pts/6`.

The ANSI codes are not to blame since I removed them and that behaviour persisted. For completeness their codes were in the form `WHITE='\033[1;37m'`

Comment: How is this a software development question, as opposed to an end-user technical support question?

Comment: Aside: `echo -e $FOO` is evil (BashPitfalls #14, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls). Use `echo -e "$FOO"`, or -- much better, for reasons given in APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html -- `printf '%b\n' "$FOO"`.

Comment: I have no idea if it something I have caused with the commands I executed or if it is due to the `less` utility. Like I previously stated I am not precisely sure if S.O is the right place.

Comment: Also consider using lower-case variable names. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that shell variables and environment variables share a namespace.

Comment: Gotcha. No, there's nothing about basic redirection you're failing to understand; this is an unexpected and undesired interaction between `less` and your terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`less -r` tells `less` to pass codes through to the terminal rather than filtering them.

**This doesn't mean that it understands what those codes do.** Not understanding them, then, means that it's no longer accurately able to detect cursor position, and can inaccurately estimate when and where line wrap occurs; hence, unexpected and undesired behavior on scrolling.

Comment: Using `-R` (capital R) may compensate, esp. if all one cares about is color.

Comment: My main issue is line breaking really.